# Switch Between Data Entities In Helper Class

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am currently working on a project at my work, I was given the task of refactoring the code to reduce the amount of code maintenance that is done of this particular class. I have two databases that have are basically the same and are being used to store different data. I am using LINQ to perform the CRUD and stored procedures. I would like to know if there is a way to create some sort of switch between the two entities and reduce the amount of code that is written

```
    private firstEntity e1= new firstEntity ();
    private secondEntity e2= new secondEntity();

    public List<tableName> CheckAccessCodesForE1()
    {
        var dbrc = e1.View.ToList();
        return dbrc;
    }

    public List<tableName> CheckAccessCodesForE2()
    {
        var dbrc = e2.View.ToList();
        return dbrc;
    }
```

As one can see the code is the same the only difference is the database being used to store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container of DbContext and then cast it as needed - assuming both Views are identical.

```
public List<Table> GetTableFromSpecifiedDB(DbContext context, string db) {
        List<Table> table;
        if(db == "firstEntity")
        {
            table = ((FirstEntity)context).Table.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            table = ((SecondEntity)context).Table.ToList();
        }

       return table
    }
```

Comment: Your solution breaks all conceivable OOP principles perhaps. Just to name few of them: Open close principle - when you will have to add new type of db, you will have add another if, then imagine you will have to add another function, to retrieve something else than list of Table objects. Polymorphism, Liskov principle - you are breaking that with casting, that is not necessary here.

Comment: This Solved my solution thanks once again for your help have a nice day

Comment: I see what you mean, however your solution doesn't really work unless you're defining the context yourself. If you're using ADO.NET and the context is automatically generated for you your solution may require more work than it's worth.

RE: open close principle, one could plausibly pass in the entity Type and use Dynamic Linq to retrieve the data from the database if a generic solution was required.

Comment: One of the requirements of the poster was to reduce *maintenance cost* and I don't think this kind of code accomplishes that.

Answer (score 2):

C#7.0 gives you opportunity to write switch case base on type, please have a look on below code

```
  public List<object> CheckAccessCodes(object entity)
    {

        switch (entity)
        {
            case FirstEntity fe:
                return fe.View.ToList();

            case SecondEntity se:
                return se.View.ToList();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

You can use any base/abstract class type instead object to make this method to more specific.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can write an interface that will contains intersect of properties that are available in both of your database contexts. Also both of your context must have shared properties in the same shape (same type, name etc.).

```
public interface IContext
{
    IQueryable<TableName> View { get; set; }
    // put other shared stuff here
}
```

Then you can implement this new interface by your context classes.

```
public class FirstEntity : IContext
{
    // first implementation db context
}

public class SecondEntity : IContext
{
    // second implementation db context
}
```

Then in the code mentioned in your question you can have only one private field with type IContext and pass particular implementation for example through constructor parameter. This let you access multiple db contexts by single logic.

```
public class MyRepository
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    public MyRepository(IContext context)
    {
       _context = context;
    }

    public List<TableName> CheckAccessCodesFor()
    {
        var dbrc = _context.View.ToList();
        return dbrc;
    }
}
```

However there are more ways how to accomplish that. You can also write an abstract class instead of interface. Then you should also think about the entity types (e.g. your `TableName` class) whether they are can be shared for both db contexts. And also it all really depends on the ORM you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing pass your db object to your function
 like this:-

```
public List<tableName> CheckAccessCodesFor_Common(DBContext db)
{
    var dbrc = db.View.ToList();
    return dbrc;
}
```

Comment: When you say DBContext is it a type that is already implemented or do I have to create it

Comment: It was a class inherited with DbContext class like for ex :- YourEntityClassName : DbContext, You should pass YourEntityClassName  in parameter

Comment: This is just a half way to increase maintainability. Passing `DbContext` each time you need to call a query on it is not pretty good practice. However it really depends on circumstances. I am wondering why you have two separate classes for two databases that are basically the same (as you stated in your question). Wouldn't it better to have just one class and two instances of that? Each for one database?